# Airplane mode automatic turn on problem

Tags: airplane-mode

Why does the airplane mode turn on automatically when both my wifi and bluetooth are turned off? How do I disable it?

Comment: What do you what to use other than wifi and Bluetooth that would be disabled by Bluetooth? Why is there a need to not have it in airplane mode if you have Bluetooth and wifi off?

Comment: When I close the lid the system puts itself in airplane mode, the problem is that it does not get out of it automatically when I open it.

Comment: Same problem - using Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04.1 on an HP Spectre Pro x360 G2.

Comment: I found a solution at: 
https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-does-airplane-mode-keep-toggling-on-the-hp-laptop-in-ubuntu-18-04/

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have mobile broadband in your computer, then turning of both WIFI and Bluetooth effectively puts the device in airplane mode.